# Hibernate: how can I retrieve last N entries with Criteria Interface?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How can I retrieve last N entries from database 
with Hibernate Criteria Interface?

```
Criteria crit = hiberSession.createCriteria(UserTable.class);
```

Or even would be better to retrieve random N entries...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the total count and then fetch the last N records.

```
        Criteria count = session.createCriteria(UserTable.class);
        count.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
        Long total = count.uniqueResult();

        int n;

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserTable.class);
        criteria.setFirstResult(total-n);
        criteria.setMaxResults(n);

        List<UserTable> list = criteria.list();
```

If you maintain the entry timestamp then you can add order and fetch the last n results

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserTable.class);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("timestamp"));
    criteria.setMaxResults(n);

    List<UserTable> list = criteria.list();
```

To get any random entries set your first result to any random value, which must be less than total count.

Comment: which approach would be more efficient?

Comment: @devesh-ahuja, If you have an index on the `timestamp` column then definitely the second approach will be faster. To be clear `last N records` only makes sense when you're sorting the records. Otherwise you'll get records based on the natural ordering of the database.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I also tried and observed the same behaviour.

Comment: It retrieves in messed up order (not ordered by id)

Answer (score 1):

The *Last* is always dependent on the `ORDER BY`. So we should firstly sort the list to be sure what is the last. Reversed order then (e.g. desc) would move the first to top

- [17.3. Ordering the results](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-ordering)

  crit.addOrder( Order.desc("name") )

Once order is defined we can use paging

- [11.4.1.5. Pagination](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing-pagination)

> If you need to specify bounds upon your result set, that is, the maximum number of rows you want to retrieve and/or the first row you want to retrieve, you can use methods of the Query interface:

```
Query q = sess.createQuery("from DomesticCat cat");
q.setFirstResult(20);
q.setMaxResults(10);
List cats = q.list();
```

in this case, we would have it similar

```
...
crit.setFirstResult(20);
crit.setMaxResults(10);
...
```